# [Android][Browsing Files] n-Depth Array

Tags: java, arrays, database, tree

i need to write a Test for a Media browser. 
The test should automatically go trough all possible paths.

The Problem:
I have just a File List which contains the Mp3 files with Metatags like artist, album, genre, etc ...

The Test ...
... should browse automatic trough the Files depending on their tags.

genre -> artist -> album -> title

Let's say i have three files:

```
File 1 <b>Artist1</b> Album1_1 <b>Title1_1_1</b> Pop_genre  
File 2 <b>Artist1</b> Album1_2 <b>Title1_2_1</b> Pop_genre  
File 3 <b>Artist2</b> Album2_1 <b>Title2_1_2</b> Rock_genre
```

Then the Output of the Test should be something like:

```
1. Move to genre="Pop_genre"
2. Move to genre="Pop_genre" AND artist="Artist1"
3. Move to genre="Pop_genre" AND artist="Artist1" AND album="Album1_1"
4. Move to genre="Pop_genre" AND artist="Artist1"
5. Move to genre="Pop_genre" AND artist="Artist1" AND album="Album2_1"
6. Move to genre="Pop_genre" AND artist="Artist1"
7. Move to genre="Pop_genre"
8. Move to genre="Rock_genre"
9. Move to genre="Rock_genre" AND artist="Artist2"
10. Move to genre="Rock_genre" AND artist="Artist2" AND album="Album2_1"
```

Test end ...

I know that is pretty heavy ... any suggestions ?

Offtopic: We need table support in markdown ...